# OpenCart: How to add link to images

Tags: php, html, opencart

My download.php page uses href to send a user to a custom script I made, and this script will display images on a folder for the user to download.

However, in my custom script, I added:
class ControllerAccountDownload extends Controller {
    public function index() {

So that I can use the $this pointer, but an error comes up saying that the script can't find the class "Controller"

I have a strong suspicion that the solution is to go to the controller script and add in my custom script. Can anyone help me with this?

TLDR: how do i allow my custom script to work with controller

Answer (score 0):

There is ControllerAccountDownload class in catalog/controller/account/download.php, why not modify it?

Comment: that is exactly what I'm doing. 

Part of my download.php modifying is that, I want to generate links to images for each product they bought. I am having trouble generating the routes, cause this is a completely custom script.